# How to add input parameters for matlab application execution

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm writing a script in MatLab and I need to execute a program (written in C) as one of the lines (it generates an output file).

My current code is:

```
!collect2.exe infile.csv    <-- I want to be able to change this to a variable but I can't
```

My question is, is there a way for me to either:

```
A. put a variable in place of infile.csv such as
!collect2.exe filedir
or
B. run multiple files without a variable
```

Thanks in advance :)

***Edit:***

```
filedir = input('What is the directory with quotes?');
!cd /
cmdString = ['cd ', filedir];
system(cmdString);
```

***Edit #2:***

Never mind, I fixed the issue. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `system` function.

Example:

```
filename = 'infile.csv';
cmdString = ['collect2.exe ', filename];
system(cmdString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a variable called filename, per your example it would be

```
filename='infile.csv';
```

or alternately have you tried using this to launch multiple files at once?

```
!collect.exe {infile.csv,infile1.csv,infile2.csv};
```